# Take some value from a vector

Tags: c++, vector

i have 2 vectors like these:

```
std::vector <svm_node *> vettProbX;

std::vector <double> vettProbY;
```

Where `svm_node` is a structure.

I need to take, from  these vectors, only an element each 50. For example, if the dimension of `vettProbY` was 1000, i would obtain only 20 values (0,50,100,150,200..).
How can i implement this algorithm for both of them?

i think that for the `vettProbY` i could implement something like this:

```
std:: vector <double> NewVettProbY

for(int i=0; i<vettProbY.size(); i++)
{
 if((i % 50)=0)
  NewVettProbY.push_back(vettProbY[i]);
}
```

but i don't know how to implement the same thing for the vector `vettProbX`.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why can't you do it exactly the same way? (Although the method you have doesn't seem too efficient, why not just increement i by 50 each time?)

Comment: makes it sense to put both - the svm_node* and the double - together? Like this: struct Foo { svm_node* nd_; double d_; }; std::vector< Foo > vettProb;

Comment: Does it need to be a new vector, or can it be a [stride view](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/index.html#range-views)?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to note is that you are storing **raw** pointers inside `vettProbX`:

> ```
> std::vector<svm_node *> vettProbX;
> ```

Are you sure about that? Raw pointers inside STL containers are fine if they are *observing* pointers; but *owning* raw pointers are bad and source of leaks!

Another option can be using an STL container with a *smart* pointer like `shared_ptr`, e.g.:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<svm_node>> vettProbX;
```

(For *unique* ownership, `std::unique_ptr` is fine, and more efficient and more lightweight than `shared_ptr`.)

Anyway, you may want to use some code like this:

```
std::vector<double> newVettProbY;
for (size_t i = 0; i < vettProbY.size(); i += 50 /* step */)
{
    newVettProbY.push_back(vettProbY[i]);
}


// Assuming:
// std::vector<std::shared_ptr<svm_node>> vettProbX;

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<svm_node>> newVettProbX;
for (size_t i = 0; i < vettProbX.size(); i += 50 /* step */)
{
    newVettProbX.push_back(vettProbX[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you need to make copy, not reference sharing. You can do it like that:

```
std::vector <double> newVettProbY;
std::vector <svm_node *> newVettProbX;
svm_node * newNode;

for(int i=0; i<vettProbY.size(); i+=50)
{
  NewVettProbY.push_back(vettProbY[i]);
  newNode = new svm_node;
  memcpy(newNode, vettProbX[i], sizeof(svm_node));
  newVettProbX(newNode);
}
```

Here I have assumed that the two vectors are of the same size. Also note that I have improved your for cycle.

Comment: seems fine, i try it now. To delete correctly the created newNode ?

Comment: @zzari delete it when you no longer need the copy. If you do not need to copy the contents, just do not allocate with `new`. Push immediately the pointer. Btw i had a small error in my answer i will edit it immediately

Comment: Better You call the copy constructor `newNode = new svm_node(*vettProbX[i]);`

Comment: @cpp-progger are you sure such exists?

Comment: even if svm_node is a POD, it exists. Of course check for `nullptr` first.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a template function. So you can use it for all your types.

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> get_50th(std::vector<T> const& l) {
    std::vector<T> r;

    for(size_t it=0; it<l.size(); it+=50)
        r.push_back(l.at(it));

    return r;
}
```